# Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging Invalid ID

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I created a new project and installed cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging.  I'm able to receive messages and read the payload on the javascript side, but the actual notification never pops up.

I get 2 errors.
Invalid ID 0x00000000
and
Failed to load notification color.

Cordova 9.0
Cordova Android 8.0
Android Studio 4.1.3

Payload c# code

```
  var message = new MulticastMessage()
        {
            Tokens = registrationTokens,
            Notification = new Notification()
            {
                Body = body,
                Title = title,
            }
        };
```

Comment: I was able to use ForceShow to cause the notification to show up, but I still get the java errors.

Answer (score 0):

What "java errors" do you mean? You can [debug the running app from device or emulator using DDMS](https://www.andreszsogon.com/debug-cordova-android-apps-with-ddms/) to locate the exact error(s). You also failed to include sample code of the sent notification payload, please rememebr users here don't have access to your source code or your PC so we can't help you unless you expand your question.

Comment: Basically the "optional" color is returning null from NOTIFICATION_COLOR_KEY.  I added it and this fixed both errors but I thought it was optional.